# python a loop to a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, FloatField
from data.models import Plant, Recording
for plant in Plant.objects.all():
    total_ecof=0
    total_ectr=0
    for recording in Recording.objects.filter(plant__id=plant.id):
        total_ecof = total_ecof + (recording.performance_loss*recording.multiplier*recording.occurrence*plant.no_modules)/(plant.nominal_power*recording.years_of_operation*plant.nominal_power)
        total_ectr = total_ectr + ((10 + 15 + 200 + 50)*recording.occurrence+240*50*recording.occurrence*plant.no_modules)/(plant.nominal_power*3)
    print(total_ecof)
    print(total_ectr)
```

The result is:

```
0.00018
10800.049500000001
0.0002666666666666667
16000.073333333334
6.666666666666667e-05
4000.0183333333334
```

The questions is:
I am pretty sure that there is a single line code doing the same, please let me know.

Comment: Sure is, but what's the problem here? If the code is working, why do you want to destroy the readability completely?

Comment: This question probably belongs in the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ site, since your code is working?

Answer (score 0):

If you define a `lambda` that computes your local_ecof (or local_ectr), then you can use the `map(lambda, list)` function to apply the computation to all elements of the list, then use a `reduce(lambda x, y : x + y)` to sum them all.